# Poll a directory looking for files with a certain extension

Tags: vb.net

I'm writing a script to look in a directory, read the file name and use a part of the file name to run a SQL query to amend a DB, then copy the files to a new location and delete the original.

Once this is done it sends an email confirmation to a predefined email address.

I have the majority in place but am not able to Poll a Dir and process all files that may be there. Im new to this VB.net stuff and to get the other stuff working iv just named it at the beginning.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    Dim fileName As String = "C:\temp\Input\VBTEST1.success"
    Dim pathname As String = "C:\temp\Input\"
    Dim result As String
    Dim sourceDir As String = "C:\temp\Input\"
    Dim processedDir As String = "C:\temp\Input\Processed\"
    Dim fList As String() = Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir, "*.success")
    Dim sqlCommand As SqlCommand

    Public Sub Main()
      result = Path.GetFileName(fileName)

      Console.WriteLine("GetFileName('{0}') returns '{1}'", fileName, result)

      Dim betacell As String = result
      betacell = (result.Remove(7, 8))

      Dim connection As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.connectionString)
      connection.Open()

      Dim updateTransaction As SqlTransaction = connection.BeginTransaction()
      Dim sqlQ As String = "UPDATE " & My.Settings.JobTb & " SET Status = '10'  WHERE  JobNumber ='" & betacell & "'"

      sqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sqlQ, connection, updateTransaction)

      sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
      updateTransaction.Commit()
      connection.Close()
      SendEmail(My.Settings.emailUsers, "EMAIL TEXT")
      Call MoveFiles()

    End Sub
```

I'm all chuffed now as iv also managed to make it look for all files with a .success extension. Now it processes all files and not the one named in the code.

```
Module Module1    
Dim sourceDir As String = My.Settings.watchPath
Dim processedDir As String = My.Settings.processedPath

  Private loggerName As String = "EmailReleases"

Public Sub log(ex As Exception)
Console.WriteLine("Error: " & ex.ToString)
End Sub

Public Sub log(ByVal s As String)
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString & " [" & loggerName & "] " & s)
End Sub


Public Sub Main()    
Dim inputFiles As String() = Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir, "*.success")
log("Starting processing of .success files in '" & sourceDir & "' ... ")
If (inputFiles.Length > 0) Then
  Dim connection As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.connectionString)
  connection.Open()
  For Each fileName As String In inputFiles
    Dim sqlCommand As SqlCommand
    Dim fFile As New FileInfo(fileName)
    log(" Processing  " & fFile.Name)
    Dim betacell As String = fFile.Name.Substring(0, fFile.Name.Length - 8)

    'Update Status on Database with the use of the Betacell
    Dim updateTransaction As SqlTransaction = connection.BeginTransaction()
            Dim sqlQ As String = "UPDATE " & My.Settings.JobTb & " SET Status = '10'  WHERE JobNumber ='" & betacell & "'"
    sqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sqlQ, connection, updateTransaction)
    Dim result = sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

    'Email COnfirmation
    SendEmail(My.Settings.emailUsers, "EMAIL TEXT")
    If (result > 0) Then
      'Move the file
      fFile.MoveTo(processedDir & fFile.Name)
      updateTransaction.Commit() ' make sure to commit only in case moving the file is OK
    Else
      log("ERROR - Betacell '" & betacell & "' not found in database!")
      updateTransaction.Rollback()
    End If
```

Comment: A new way of [**sql-injection**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953(v=sql.105).aspx) via file names, interesting. Use [`parameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx) instead of string concatenation and don't use file names for sql commands.

Comment: use the file watcher mentioned in your previous post!

Comment: Tried that Ric but could not for the life of me make it work.

Comment: That's a shame because it is quite a nice way of doing it. All the best though!

Comment: If you can see where it would fit that would help, if not no worries i do have a roundabout way to do it. Cheers. G.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than polling a folder (i.e. checking every `n` seconds whether it has new files) it's much more efficient to have the operating system notify you of changes in that folder. You can do this by creating a [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx). There is [an example on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2).

However, if you **did** want to poll a folder, it's actually nice and easy - just wrap the following code in a [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx). Please note I normally code in C#, so apologies if the syntax is not 100%...

```
Imports System.IO

....

For Each file as String in Directory.GetFiles("C:\SomeFolder")
    DoSomethingWithFile (file)
Next
```

Comment: Cheers for this @RB, if i cant get it to work i might just lash it on a scheduled task until my skills develop enough to make this work.

Comment: Yeah - nothing wrong with that either :) Is it intended to be a Windows Service at the moment?